# cannot find symbol method getcontext

Tags: java, android, api, rest

I am new to android/java programming and I am having an issue with getting an error saying that the symbol `getContext` cannot be resolved. That system is start with `Activity` there are two `fragment`. The one is button for show Rest Api. Please help

**InstansiActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.instansi;


import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;


import com.example.instansi.adapter.InstansiAdapter;
import com.example.instansi.model.DaftarInstansiItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InstansiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private InstansiAdapter instansiAdapter;
    private RecyclerView rvInstansi;
    private com.example.instansi.viewmodel.InstansiViewModel instansiViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_instansi);

        instansiAdapter= new InstansiAdapter(getContext());
        instansiAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        rvInstansi= view.findViewById(R.id.finstansi_rv);
        rvInstansi.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),1));

        instansiViewModel= new ViewModelProvider(this).get(com.example.instansi.viewmodel.InstansiViewModel.class);
        instansiViewModel.setInstansi();
        instansiViewModel.getInstansi().observe(this, getInstansi_);

        rvInstansi.setAdapter(instansiAdapter);
    }


    private Observer<ArrayList<DaftarInstansiItem>> getInstansi_ = new Observer<ArrayList<DaftarInstansiItem>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(ArrayList<DaftarInstansiItem> daftarInstansiItems) {
            if (daftarInstansiItems != null) {
                instansiAdapter.setData(daftarInstansiItems);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way to get the activity context is putting `this`.

**In your activity for getting activity context use `this` and for getting `applicationContext()` use `getApplicationContext()`**

And the most **difference** between `activity` `context` and `application` `context` is :
`Application` `context` is tied to the `lifecycle` of the application, while the `Activity` `context` is tied to the `lifecycle` of an `Activity`.

Comment: Your welcome , what is your question about `rvInstansi= view.findViewById(R.id.finstansi_rv);`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this really provides a solution to my coding about getting activity context. And And I found a new problem with my coding that there is an error message `view` on `rvInstansi= view.findViewById(R.id.finstansi_rv);`. How about this?

Comment: In the `Activity` , you should use just `findViewById()` without any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

An `Activity` is a sub-class of `Context`, so from within an `Activity` you should just use `this` where the current context is required.